# Add-AzureNodeWebRole

Tags: node.js, azure

I try to go over the tutorial/presentation at http://learnwindowsazure.sourceforge.net/, and I cannot reproduce the steps related to node.

When I run Add-AzureNodeWebRole command I get `Add-AzureNodeWebRole : service root is invalid or empty`

Also when running the previous command, New-AzureService", there aren't any files created in the folder.

What would this exactly mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to run the cmdlet **New-AzureServiceProject** not New-AzureService.

Comment: thanks. For who might need some up to date info (for now), see https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/